# array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, int given

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am getting array_push() expect parameter one to be an array, any solution?

```
$activeCourses = array();
foreach ($allCourses as $course) {
   if (strtotime($course->end_date) > time()) {
       $activeCourses = array_push($activeCourses, $course);
   }
}
```

Comment: `$activeCourses = array_push($activeCourses, $course);` will change the value of `$activeCourses` to an integer (specifically the [number of elements in the array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)). You just need `array_push($activeCourses, $course);` to alter the array, or more simply `$activeCourses[] = $course;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have referenced the variable as an array first time. but when you are using it for array push with `$activeCourses =`  it becomes an integer field as array_push returns an integer value and then when it comes to next array push in the next iteration, your `activeCourses` variable is no longer an array. so use like

```
$activeCourses = array();
foreach ($allCourses as $course) {
   if (strtotime($course->end_date) > time()) {
       array_push($activeCourses, $course);
   }
}
```

or

```
$activeCourses = array();
foreach ($allCourses as $course) {
   if (strtotime($course->end_date) > time()) {
       $activeCourses[] = $course;
   }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest the second method as array_push as an array method consumes both time & memory more

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by you giving `$activeCourses` the value of [`array_push()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php). `array_push()` return an int value. To fix this, just update this line to not returning value, since `array_push()`'s parameter is passed by reference:

```
$activeCourses = array_push($activeCourses, $course);
```

Changed it to:

```
array_push($activeCourses, $course);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[]` more easier:

```
$activeCourses = array();
foreach ($allCourses as $course) {
   if (strtotime($course->end_date) > time()) {
     $activeCourses[] = $course;
     }
}
```